# Trailing Slash not working on Load Balancer (AWS elb)

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-elb, slash, trailing

The following command is working perfectly in `.htaccess` Magento 2.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+).html/
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]
```

But when we enable Load balancer (AWS ELB) it stops working. Please help in this regard.

Comment: You will need to define *"stops working."* What does it do, instead of what you expect?  What is in the ALB logs?  What is in the web server logs?

Comment: Stops working mean it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Right... and does what, instead?  Returns an error?  Returns different content?  If it isn't redirecting, then it must be doing something different.  Also, is this a Classic ELB or an Application Load Balancer (ALB, ELB/2.0)?

Comment: It has been resolved by this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\.html/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1.html [R=301,L]